Deploying express api from monorepo failing on render
I am trying to deploy my express backend on render as a web service from a mono repo (github link of repo : GitHub - kartik-chausali/code-arena-turbo)
this backend uses different modules which i created in my monorepo but while deploying on render it gives error could not resolve those modules
build logs on render
folder structure of my monorepo
package.json of my submission-callback express server
i've set the source directory as apps/submission-callback (submission-callback is my express server)
i expected render to resolve these modules automatically but it is not working
